# How to register an AppleScript as a potential default web browser?

Tags: macos, applescript

I've written an AppleScript that I want to set as the default browser.

I've added a `CFBundleDocumentTypes` section to the p-list (copied from Safari) and rebuilt the launch services database, but that didn't work.

The script doesn't show up in the Safari default browser list. If I choose it manually in that preferences dialog, it's ignored, and Safari becomes the default browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding the `CFBundleURLTypes` and the sub-key `LSIsAppleDefaultForScheme`?

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>Web site URL</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>http</string>
            <string>https</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForScheme</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Not sure that it will help, but I have noticed these keys in the info.plist of all the apps that I have checked that show up in that browser list.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that was the main thing I was missing. I found this article which specifically addresses the issue: http://www.macosautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/index.html